# How can i reset my variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have declared @@category_count in my UsersHelper and i have problem because after reload my var is not reset?

```
module UsersHelper

    @@category_count = Hash.new(0) 

    def category_counter(name)
        @@category_count[name] += 1
    end
```

Before reload:
A -> 1,
B -> 2

After reload:
A -> 2,
B -> 4

Comment: Why do you define class variable? How about define instance variable?

Comment: because i get ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)

Answer (score 2):

You should define instance variable:

```
def category_counter(name)
    @category_count ||= Hash.new(0) 
    @category_count[name] += 1
end
```

Comment: Don't use @@ if you don't understand problems with [global variables](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).